# CYK algorithm - how to handle unknown terminals given in a sentence to parse?

Tags: context-free, parsers, natural-language-processing, lexical-analysis

There is a given treebank which we derive the Probabilistic context free grammar.
I wonder how do one handles with a given sentence which includes terminals that don't exist in the derived rules?
Is there a kind of smoothing for this case?
Considering we use CYK to get the parse tree of the given sentence.